# Initialising VMware Player 14 on Fedora 28: Unable to compile Virtual Machine Monitor

Tags: fedora, vmware

As I was installing VMware Player 14 in Fedora 28, I wasn't able to compile the vmmon module for executing VMware. The vmnet was successfully compiled but for the vmmon it occur the following errors:

```
/tmp/modconfig-rBg8Xn/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIF_InitUptime’:
/tmp/modconfig-rBg8Xn/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1779:4: error: implicit
declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘init_timers’? 
[-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
init_timer(&uptimeState.timer);
^~~~~~~~~~
init_timers
/tmp/modconfig-rBg8Xn/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1780:31: error: assignment
to ‘void (*)(struct timer_list *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘void 
(*)(long unsigned int)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
uptimeState.timer.function = HostIFUptimeResyncMono;
                           ^
```

The command I ran was:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Also, all the kernel modules are installed correctly according to the command:

```
 sudo dnf install gcc glibc-headers kernel-devel kernel-headers patch
```

How can I fix this? Have I downloaded the wrong modules?

Comment: I would use the open vm tools instead.

Comment: Your OS is not on the supported list for the player, so it's not guaranteed to work. The timer interface in the recent kernels has changed, so the player source code is outdated. This would compile on an earlier kernel source.

Comment: Well, if VMware doesn't support Fedora 28, I'll just have to use Oracle VirtualBox. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because of a recent breaking change in the Linux Kernel. The issue has been reported, for example,  [here](http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=2129)

> Kernel 4.15-rc1 has been released, and brief details are here:  http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1711.3/00971.html
>
> With VMware 14.0.0 – plus the 4.14 vmmon patch – vmmon breaks again [...]

The possible solution is to apply the patch located [here](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules) for VMWare.